# Loading UIview background fastly using image

Tags: iphone, ios

Iam developing one application.In that i want to set the uiview background as image.That image size is 1.6 mb.I followed the below code.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

But it takes more time compared to small size image.So please  help me how to load 3mb size of image also like as small size of image.

Comment: You can optimize the image size using the tool ImageOptim

Comment: Just i changed the CompressPNG file to NO in build settings.Then also it will take more time to load.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the drawing operations on a background queue, so it won't freeze the UI:

```
CGRect imgRect = self.view.bounds;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgRect.size);
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] drawInRect:imgRect];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIColor* bgcolor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.view.backgroundColor = bgcolor;
    });
});
```

Also optimize the image by using the tool [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com).

Comment: Optimize the image means what can i do?

Comment: ImageOptim optimizes images so that they take up less disk space and load faster. Simply drag'n'drop the image file to the window.

Comment: But I am getting the images from server.

Answer (score 0):

Its best if you `resize` `image` and then add in `Application bundle` to execute faster.

here I think there is `no need` get `image` firstly for `resizing` for `UIView` s `pattern image` in `background`.

You can `solve memory issue` like this:

```
 NSString *imgfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"];
 UIImage *currentImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgfile];
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:currentImage];
```

Refer [ios-imagenamed-vs-imagewithcontentsoffile](http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2012/04/19/ios-imagenamed-vs-imagewithcontentsoffile/) link.

**EDIT** : Use @phix23 answer for smooth UI